# What is the difference?

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me the difference between:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

and:

```
var someVar = {
    ready : function() {
    }
}
```

or:

```
$(function() {
});
```

I have seen things started in all three ways and I am never sure which way to start. Is it different for different situations or uses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first and third examples are identical - jQuery offers the third syntax as a shortcut for the first one.  Your middle example creates an object literal called `someVar` that has a `ready` method (this doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery).

Comment: Ah. Well I guess it is easy to think the middle one did have something to do with JQuery as it has the ready : function() in there and I see it used on any number of JQuery tutorials. I like the last one anyway. Shorter .. less code.

Thanks
Dave